# In google sheet script I don't get the current value of the cell in edition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheet script I have several cells to fill. When is it's finish, user will click on a button that will call a function.

The problem is that the LAST cell is ignored if the user still have the focus on it. The use HAVE TO click on another cell to "save" is last modification.

Exemple :
Write some text in cell K10 and click on the button that will call btn_save

```
function btn_save (){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  if (spreadsheet.getRange('K10').getValue() == ''){
    Browser.msgBox('Empty :( ');
  }
  else{
    Browser.msgBox('Yeah you got it !');
  }
 }
```

=> you will not have the text !
If after writing some text in cell K10 you click on another cell BEFORE clicking on the btn_save you will have the data...

This is really a problem for me, because the use will forget to click somewhere else before clicking on the button and we will have an issue ( lost of data).

In other tools you don't have to click somewhere else to save your data. like when you write and email, when you click on "send" your email is sent with all the data, event if the focuse is still on the Body, subject, ...

I really hope that there is a function like : SaveCurrentCell, Simulate EnterKEY, or whatever :)

Thanks for you help.

Best Regards,

Adrien

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the cell a user is editing? (Google Sheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410007/how-do-i-change-the-cell-a-user-is-editing-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternate solution is to use [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms) to run your save function. This forces the user to click on the menu items, this invariably causes the program to accept the changes made to the cell.

If I understand correctly you are currently using a [clickable image](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) currently to run your function. This doesn't update the changes to the cell currently on, unless enter is pressed.

You can create a menu item like so:

```
 //onOpen will run each time the spreadsheet is opened 
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu("Save Files")
         .addItem("save", "btn_save") //Binds the function btn_save to save menu item
         .addToUi();
    }


 function btn_save (){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush() //apply all pending changes!
  if (spreadsheet.getRange('K10').getValue() == ''){
    Browser.msgBox('Empty :( ');
  }
  else{
    Browser.msgBox('Yeah you got it !');
  }
 }
```

Finally, onOpen is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopene) which will create your menu item each time the spreadsheet is opened. So once your copy this code to your spreadsheet make sure you reload the spreadsheet or run the onOpen function to create the menu item.